# how can i make a decorder and encoder?

Tags: javascript, html, encoder, decoder

I made my own digital language and i want to make a decoder and an encoder for that, so for example when i write down

> "bees"

it gives me something like

> "$@@%"

and when i write `

> "$@@%"

` it gives me

> "bees"

so it encodes things according to the info i give my website
like i tell my website that $ is B and other letters are other symbols.
how can i make this in html and javescript?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "too broad" because there are a ton of ways to implement something like this.    "How do I get started" is not a good question here, rather try something and ask about problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suppose you just need a 1 to 1 mapping, and then a method to encode and one to decode your text.

probably something similar to this

```js
const alphabet = { 'a': '$', 'b': '?'} //here you define your mapping

encode = text => text.split('').map(ch => alphabet[ch]).join('');

decode = text => text.split('').map(ch => Object.keys(alphabet)
.find(letter => alphabet[letter] === ch)).join('');

console.log(encode('ab'));
console.log(decode('$?'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an interview question so I wont write it but you can use a simple replace method that you run the string through. it could be the same for both encode and decode IF you never use real letters in your language.

NOTE: javascript replace will only replace the first char it finds that matches you will need to use the regex version or loop over each char one at a time.